# using IoC container in azure functions

Tags: azure, inversion-of-control, azure-functions

I have been used to writing Windows Services using [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) to do all stuff which cannot be done in a web request and am slowly moving to using azure functions.

With topshelf I could generally do

1. scan and register on start of a service
2. use nested container for each ticket / request

How can I use IOC in an azure function call ? Should I be using it at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't currently a way to do IOC in a natural way in Azure Functions. Generally you'd want to initialize your IOC container at application startup, but we don't currently give you a way to do that. We have an open issue in our repo related to that [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/586). Furthermore, we'd have to make this container available to Function instances.