# Using IConfigurationRoot when registering services for DI in Azure Functions beta?

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, configuration, .net-core, azure-functions

I want to be able to use dependency injection in my Azure Functions VS 2017 project (I'm using SDK v1.0.6). DI doesn't seem to work out-of-the-box yet, so I'm using [Boris Wilhelms workaround](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/azure-functions-proper-dependency-injection/).

When I register some services, I need to be able to use a connection string from a configuration object. I found [a good article by Jon Gallant](https://blog.jongallant.com/2018/01/azure-function-config/) that describes the new way to build an IConfigurationRoot object. However, that approach relies on a ExecutionContext object, which I don't think is available in Boris' InjectConfiguration class.

Any ideas how I can use my

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47809098/1171619) on how to read connection strings in v2, without `ExecutionContext`

Comment: *Any ideas how I can use my* - What happened, did you fall asleep at the keyboard?

Comment: I have updated my DI solution to Azure Function v2 where it is also now possible to access the configuration for your IoC configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430342/using-ioc-container-in-azure-functions